# history.listen() replacement in react router V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm upgrading react router V5 application to react router v6. I have come across some snippet which I'm not able to convert to V6. I tried enough and looked at different solutions over internet but nothing seem to work for me.

Code that I want to convert to V6,

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"; 

export default () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const history = useHistory(); // the browser history object  
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const { onParentNavigate } = mount(ref.current, {
      onNavigate: ({ pathname: nextPathname }) => {
        const { pathname } = history.location;                 
        if (pathname !== nextPathname) {

          history.push(nextPathname); //<<<<< how to convert this to v6 ?
        }
      },
    });
 
    history.listen(onParentNavigate); //<<<<<< how to convert this to v6 ?
  }, []);
 
  return <div ref={ref} />;
};
```

**MyVersion using V6**

```
const ref = useRef(null);
  //  const navigation = useContext(UNSAFE_NavigationContext).navigator as BrowserHistory();
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // V6
  const location = useLocation(); // V6

  useEffect(() => {
    const { onParentNavigate } = dashboardMount(ref.current, {

      onNavigate: (result: any) => {
        const { pathname } = location;
        if (pathname !== result.location.pathname) {

          navigate(result.location.pathname, { replace: true }); // This is not throwing any error but not giving expected outcome

        }
      }
    })

    navigate(onParentNavigate); // This not throwing any error but not giving me expected outcome as well

  }, []);

  return <div ref={ref}></div>
```

**Any pointer or solution will be highly appreciated !**

Answer (score 0):

You could likely use the [`UNSAFE_NavigationContext`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L109-L127) exported from `react-router-dom` to access the raw "history" navigator object.

> ```
> ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> // DANGER! PLEASE READ ME!
> // We provide these exports as an escape hatch in the event that you need any
> // routing data that we don't provide an explicit API for. With that said, we
> // want to cover your use case if we can, so if you feel the need to use these
> // we want to hear from you. Let us know what you're building and we'll do our
> // best to make sure we can support you!
> //
> // We consider these exports an implementation detail and do not guarantee
> // against any breaking changes, regardless of the semver release. Use with
> // extreme caution and only if you understand the consequences. Godspeed.
> ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> /** @internal */
> export {
>   UNSAFE_NavigationContext,
>   UNSAFE_LocationContext,
>   UNSAFE_RouteContext,
> } from "react-router";
> ```

Example:

```
import React, { useContext, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { UNSAFE_NavigationContext } from "react-router-dom";

export default () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const { navigator } = useContext(UNSAFE_NavigationContext); // the browser history object  
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const { onParentNavigate } = mount(ref.current, {
      onNavigate: ({ pathname: nextPathname }) => {
        const { pathname } = navigator.location;                 
        if (pathname !== nextPathname) {

          navigator.push(nextPathname);
        }
      },
    });
 
    const unlisten = navigator.listen(onParentNavigate);

    return unlisten; // <-- cleanup listener on component unmount
  }, []);
 
  return <div ref={ref} />;
};
```

Comment: what is `mount`?

Comment: @AdventMedia `mount` and `dashboardMount` appear to be functions presumed to be elsewhere in the OP's code. Neither is a `react` or `react-router-dom` function if that's what you are wondering or concerned about.

Comment: This answer gave me an idea. What I did, was to create a context in React and pass down the router object, so I could use useContext and the router.subscribe down in the component hierarchy.

Comment: @csikos.balint Good idea. And thanks for a reminder that I may need to update this answer to reflect some of the more recent RRDv6 changes.